# Overloading ++ and -- checking on privately accessible min or max values

Tags: c#

How do I overload ++ and -- templates to increment and decrement with a min and max that is enforced at runtime within the operator overloads checking for max and min properties accessible only within the ++ and -- overloaded templates.

In this c# "pseudo code example"[sic] "not using overloaded templates"[sic]:

```
int x = 500;
int index = 503; 

while(index > 0) {
   x--; // where operator overload min=0 and max = 1000;
   index -= 1;
 }
Console.Write("x={0}",x); // should see x=0 

index = 0
while(index < 1050) {
   x++; // where operator overload min=0 and max = 1000;
   index += 1;
 }

Console.Write("x={0}",x); // should see x=1000
```

Comment: I don't see a template there... C# doesn't even have templates. Are you referring to generics?

Comment: I'm confused - `x` is an `int` and does not have a `min` property (at least not a configurable one).

Comment: You can add the min on the condition of the while cycle.

Comment: Its "++" and "--" is the template

Comment: This is quite far from C# code

Comment: @ZoltánTamási I'm assuming OP forgot to copy the `/*` and `*/` before and after the snippet :).

Comment: I think, perhaps, what you are looking to do is to create a new class, RangeLimitedInt32, that behaves the same as an Int32 but which has a Min and a Max.

Comment: @DaveMackersie Either that, or he wants a "safe" increment/decrement that won't wrap, in which case he just needs to use the checked construct and catch OverflowException

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Before you even begin to attempt to overload the ++ operator in C# you should have an extremely strong understanding of how it works; it does not work like it does in C++.  Read this to start with: http://blog.coverity.com/2013/09/24/increment-semantics/#.VCyIETp0y4A

Answer (score 3):

You question is very ill formulated..., but i think you're looking for

```
int max = 1000;
int min = 0;
int x = 500;

//Increment to max
while(x < max) x++;

Console.WriteLine(x); //Here you will see 1000

//Decrement to min
while(x > min) x--;

Console.WriteLine(x) //Here you will see 0
```

In the future, please be more specific when asking questions

Updated! From your comment i understand now that you want to overload the operators:

```
public static int operator ++ (int x)
{
    if(x > xmax) return x;
    return x++;
}

public static int operator -- (int x)
{
    if(x < xmin) return x;
    return x--;
}
```

This is how to do operator overloading but the above example won't work as you can overload primitive types as int, bool, etc.. But this would work for an object

Comment: Possible, but I'd really know what on earth the OP means by "template" before seeing any answers...

Comment: I'm trying to get the ++ and -- to do the checking, not the while loop.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I think it's pretty safe to assume OP is talking about operator overloading.

Comment: @Michael I'd agree, except you can't overload operators for basic types like int. So either he doesn't know that, or its something else.

Comment: @Michael never mind, it would appear that he just doesn't know that.

Comment: I am highly skeptical that your update would compile on a standard int, especially considering that "max" is not a property of int.

Comment: I only made the sample to show an example of how to do operator overloading. I added an text below that it is only showing the concept as you either way can't overload operators for primitive types :-)